# CI with QAC + Gitlab / Integration

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, qa-c

I am trying to integrate QAC static analysis checks into Gitlab CI workflow (I could add Jenkins if needed) but I didn't find any guide/material. Is there anyone that tried to integrate Gitlab CI and PRQA/QAC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on what you're trying to achieve, and the version of QAC you're using.

Assuming you're using a recent release there is a Jenkins Plugin (instructions [here](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/qac-for-jenkins/Helix-QAC-Plug-in-for-Jenkins-Manual.pdf).

Assuming that you're trying to block commits based on analysis results, and that you're using QAC 9.0 or later: the steps are:

1. Clone the project to a machine with a compiler installed.
2. Create a project, setting an appropriate CCT and RCF for your needs.
3. Use QACLI Sync to populate the project (watch the build process)
4. Run analysis
5. Parse the output from QACLI View Summary to determine whether or not to accept the commit
6. Feed this information back to gitlab.